# c# code to validate organisation/company number?

Tags: c#, javascript, regex, validation

I have a javascript which validates an organisation/company number but I need it in c#. Does anyone have something like this lying around?

It's not an assignment and I could translate it myself, but if someone's done it already I wouldn't have to go through the work =)
If it's country specific I need to use it in Sweden.

Here it is in javascript, found at http://www.jojoxx.net

```
function organisationsnummer(nr) {
    this.valid = false;

    if (!nr.match(/^(\d{1})(\d{5})\-(\d{4})$/))
    {
        return false;
    }

    this.group = RegExp.$1;
    this.controldigits = RegExp.$3;
    this.alldigits = this.group + RegExp.$2 + this.controldigits;

    if (this.alldigits.substring(2, 3) < 2)
    {
        return false
    }

    var nn = "";

    for (var n = 0; n < this.alldigits.length; n++)
    {
        nn += ((((n + 1) % 2) + 1) * this.alldigits.substring(n, n + 1));
    }

    this.checksum = 0;

    for (var n = 0; n < nn.length; n++)
    {
        this.checksum += nn.substring(n, n + 1) * 1;
    }

    this.valid = (this.checksum % 10 == 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you provide some examples?

Comment: To also allow 'personnummer', uncomment this: if (this.alldigits.substring(2, 3) < 2)
    {
        return false
    }

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
static bool OrganisationsNummer(string nr)
{
    Regex rg = new Regex(@"^(\d{1})(\d{5})\-(\d{4})$");
    Match matches = rg.Match(nr);

    if (!matches.Success)
        return false;

    string group = matches.Groups[1].Value;
    string controlDigits = matches.Groups[3].Value;
    string allDigits = group + matches.Groups[2].Value + controlDigits;

    if (Int32.Parse(allDigits.Substring(2, 1)) < 2)
        return false;

    string nn = "";

    for (int n = 0; n < allDigits.Length; n++)
    {
        nn += ((((n + 1) % 2) + 1) * Int32.Parse(allDigits.Substring(n, 1)));
    }

    int checkSum = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < nn.Length; n++)
    {
        checkSum += Int32.Parse(nn.Substring(n, 1));
    }

    return checkSum % 10 == 0 ? true : false;
}
```

tests:

```
Console.WriteLine(OrganisationsNummer("556194-7986")); # => True
Console.WriteLine(OrganisationsNummer("802438-3534")); # => True
Console.WriteLine(OrganisationsNummer("262000-0113")); # => True
Console.WriteLine(OrganisationsNummer("14532436-45")); # => False
Console.WriteLine(OrganisationsNummer("1")); # => False
```

Comment: Actually that implementation is not solid, at all. For instance, 556194-7986 is not a valid personal number, since there is no month 61. Also, for ppl over 100y old, the - character is changed to a + character, etc. See http://sv.wikipedia.org/wiki/Personnummer

Comment: ^([25789]{1})(\d{5})\-(\d{4})$ This also contains the valid first digits for a Swedish Organisationnummer

Answer (score 2):

There is an online [JavaScript to C# converter](http://www.m2h.nl/files/js_to_c.php).

Likely there are [tons of others](http://www.google.com/search?q=convert%20javascript%20to%20c#), probably one is at least suitable to assist you in doing parts of the converstion.

On the other hand, it seems to be rather simple to manually convert those few lines.

Comment: Haha, I feel a bit stupid now that I didn't google before posting =/

Comment: So you "StackOverflow-ed" instead, which is roughly the equivalent of what Googling is for the "normal people" :-)

Comment: That's what StackOverflow will do to you...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

More solid implementation

```
/// <summary>
/// Immutable value type for storing personal numbers
/// </summary>
public struct PersonalNumber : IEquatable<PersonalNumber>
{
    private const string YearHundredOpt = @"(19|20)?"; // 19 or 20 only (optional)
    private const string YearDecade = @"(\d{2})"; // any two digits
    private const string Month = @"(0[1-9]|10|11|12)"; // 01 to 12
    private const string Day = @"(0[1-9]|1\d|2\d|30|31)"; // 01 to 31
    private const string SeparatorAndLastFourOpt = @"([-\+]?)(\d{4})?"; // optional - or + followed by any four digits (optional)

    private const string RegExForValidation =
        "^" + YearHundredOpt + YearDecade + Month + Day + SeparatorAndLastFourOpt + "$";

    private static readonly Regex personNoRegex = new Regex(RegExForValidation, RegexOptions.Compiled);

    private readonly string rawPersonalNumber;
    private readonly string personalNumber;
    private readonly bool isValid;
    private readonly bool isPlus100YearsOld;

    public PersonalNumber(string personalNumber)
    {
        rawPersonalNumber = personalNumber;

        var matches = personNoRegex.Matches(personalNumber);
        var normalizedYYMMDDXXXC = string.Empty;
        isPlus100YearsOld = false;
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            if (match.Success)
            {
                normalizedYYMMDDXXXC = match.Groups[2].Value + match.Groups[3].Value +
                              match.Groups[4].Value + match.Groups[6].Value;
                if (match.Groups[5].Success)
                {
                    isPlus100YearsOld = match.Groups[5].Value == "+";
                }
                break;
            }
        }

        if (normalizedYYMMDDXXXC.Length > 6)
        {
            isValid = personNoRegex.IsMatch(personalNumber) && LuhnAlgorithm.ValidateChecksum(normalizedYYMMDDXXXC);
        }
        else
        {
            isValid = personNoRegex.IsMatch(personalNumber);
        }

        this.personalNumber = string.IsNullOrEmpty(normalizedYYMMDDXXXC) ? rawPersonalNumber : normalizedYYMMDDXXXC;
    }

    public string Number { get { return personalNumber; } }
    public bool IsPlus100YearsOld { get { return isPlus100YearsOld; } }
    public bool IsValid { get { return isValid; } }
    public bool IsMale { get { return !IsFemale; } }

    public bool IsFemale
    {
        get
        {
            var genderCharacter = personalNumber.Substring(personalNumber.Length - 2, 1); // second to last character
            return int.Parse(genderCharacter) % 2 == 0; // even = female, odd = male
        }
    }

    public override string ToString() { return Number; }

    public bool Equals(PersonalNumber other)
    {
        return Equals(other.personalNumber, personalNumber);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (ReferenceEquals(null, obj)) return false;
        if (obj.GetType() != typeof (PersonalNumber)) return false;
        return Equals((PersonalNumber) obj);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int result = (rawPersonalNumber != null ? rawPersonalNumber.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result*397) ^ (personalNumber != null ? personalNumber.GetHashCode() : 0);
            result = (result*397) ^ isValid.GetHashCode();
            return result;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator ==(PersonalNumber left, PersonalNumber right)
    {
        return left.Equals(right);
    }

    public static bool operator !=(PersonalNumber left, PersonalNumber right)
    {
        return !left.Equals(right);
    }
}
```

and some tests for it

```
[TestClass]
public class PersonalNumberFixture
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Ctor_PersonalNumber_AsUnformatted()
    {
        AssertExpectedNumber("7102240475", "7102240475");
        AssertExpectedNumber("197102240475", "7102240475");
        AssertExpectedNumber("19710224-0475", "7102240475");
        AssertExpectedNumber("710224-0475", "7102240475");
    }

    private static void AssertExpectedNumber(string number, string expectedNumber)
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedNumber, new PersonalNumber(number).Number);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void FiltersAndRemovesPlusAndMinusCharactersCorrectly()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual("7102240475", new PersonalNumber("710224-0475").Number);
        Assert.AreEqual("7102240475", new PersonalNumber("710224+0475").Number);

        Assert.AreEqual("7102240475", new PersonalNumber("19710224-0475").Number);
        Assert.AreEqual("7102240475", new PersonalNumber("19710224+0475").Number);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void PlusAndMinusCharactersOnlyAllowedInCertainPositions()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("710224-0475").IsValid);
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("710224+0475").IsValid);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("71022404-75").IsValid);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("71022404+75").IsValid);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("710-224-0475").IsValid);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("710224+04+75").IsValid);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void MaleAndFemale_CorrectlyIdentified()
    {
        // female
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("551213-7986").IsMale);
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("551213-7986").IsFemale);

        // male
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("710224-0475").IsMale);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("710224-0475").IsFemale);
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("19710224-0475").IsMale);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("19710224-0475").IsFemale);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Ctor_ValidPersonalNumbers_ParsedAsValid()
    {
        TestLoop_ValidPersonalNumbers(new[] { "7102240475", "197102240475", "19710224-0475", "710224-0475", "801231+3535", "630215" });
    }

    private static void TestLoop_ValidPersonalNumbers(IEnumerable<string> personalNumbers)
    {
        foreach (var personalNumber in personalNumbers)
        {
            var pn = new PersonalNumber(personalNumber);

            Assert.IsTrue(pn.IsValid, string.Format("Pno = '{0}'", personalNumber));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void ToString_EqualsNormalizedNumber()
    {
        Assert.AreEqual(new PersonalNumber("460126").ToString(), new PersonalNumber("460126").Number);
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Ctor_InvalidPersonalNumbers_ParsedAsNotValid()
    {
        TestLoop_InvalidPersonalNumbers(new[] { "127102240475", "19710XY40475", "19710224=0475", "1971", "14532436-45", "556194-7986", "262000-0113", "460531-12" });
    }

    private static void TestLoop_InvalidPersonalNumbers(IEnumerable<string> personalNumbers)
    {
        foreach (var personalNumber in personalNumbers)
        {
            var pn = new PersonalNumber(personalNumber);

            Assert.IsFalse(pn.IsValid, string.Format("Pno = '{0}'", personalNumber));
        }
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void TwoNumbers_ConsideredEqual_IfNormalizedNumbersAreEqual()
    {
        new PersonalNumber("710224-0475");
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("800212").Equals(new PersonalNumber("19800212")));
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("800212").Equals(new PersonalNumber("800212")));
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("8002121234").Equals(new PersonalNumber("19800212-1234")));

        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("800212").Equals(new PersonalNumber("900212")));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void EqualsOperatorOverloaded_AsEquals()
    {
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("800212") == new PersonalNumber("19800212"));
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("800212") == new PersonalNumber("800212"));
        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("8002121234") == new PersonalNumber("19800212-1234"));

        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("800212") != new PersonalNumber("900212"));
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void IsPlus100YearsOld()
    {
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("800213").IsPlus100YearsOld);
        Assert.IsFalse(new PersonalNumber("800213-0123").IsPlus100YearsOld);

        Assert.IsTrue(new PersonalNumber("800213+0123").IsPlus100YearsOld);
    }
}
```